# update parse object using BeforeSave

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm making a simple money transaction app where `user1` transfer money to `user2` using parse.com and cloud code to give `user1` permission using masterkey to override all other permissions.

```
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery(user.getClassName());
            Log.d("class found : ",String.valueOf(user.getClassName()));
            parseQuery.whereMatches("AccountNumber", mAccountNumber.getText().toString().trim());
            parseQuery.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(final ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
                    if (parseObject != null) {
                        Log.d("userID",String.valueOf(parseObject.getObjectId()));
                        balance = Integer.parseInt(mbalance.getText().toString());
                        q = parseObject.getInt("balance");
                        parseObject.put("balance", balance + q);
                        parseObject.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                if (e == null) {
                                    Toast.makeText(TransferToAccount.this, "DOne!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("Exception", "1");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        Log.d("Exception", "2");
                        Toast.makeText(TransferToAccount.this, "No user found ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
```

and this is the could code :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.User, function(request, response) {
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 
var user = request.user;
if (user.existed()) { return; }
user.setACL(new Parse.ACL(user));
user.save();
// add user to role
var roleName = "member";
var roleQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
roleQuery.equalTo("name", roleName);
roleQuery.first().then(function(role) {
role.getUsers().add(user);
// save role
return role.save();
});
```

when I try to transfer I get an `Exception` :

```
W/System.err: com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

and

```
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

sorry if I made myself unclear.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Parse is being shut down so it would be best to move away from it as soon as you can. In the meantime though I hope someone can help.

Comment: @Vidia I'm using parse for my college project so that won't be a problem atm , thanks anyway .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading [this](http://blog.parse.com/learn/secure-your-app-from-the-data-browser-with-pointer-permissions/) , I could solve my problem by creating a second class with a pointer to `_User` without the need to cloud code .

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign a role to a user before he is saved. Try to change it to afterSave trigger.

Comment: Result: TypeError: Cannot call method 'getUsers' of undefined
    at e.<anonymous> (main.js:19:10)
    at e.i (Parse.js:14:27703)
    at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:27063)
    at e.<anonymous> (Parse.js:14:27774)
    at e.i (Parse.js:14:27703)
    at Parse.js:14:28316
    at l (Parse.js:14:28120)
    at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:28301)
    at e.i (Parse.js:14:27748)
    at e.a.value (Parse.js:14:27063)

Comment: it seems that it doesnt recognize getUsers(), I dont know if it is some of your  defined functions or not but I would delete it and try just something similar to this `role.relation("users").add(user);`